# Can "django-nested-admin" sort the top level items in select-to-change list in addition to inline items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-nested-admin

I could sort inline items with [**django-nested-admin**](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) as shown below:

[image]

But, I couldn't sort **the top level items** in **select-to-change list** as shown below. (In addition, I also couldn't sort it with the combination of [**django-nested-admin**](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [**django-admin-sortable2**](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2)):

[image]

This is the code in **"models.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position", null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position", null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position", null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, this is the code in **"admin.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from nested_admin import SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline, NestedModelAdmin
from .models import Country, Province, City

class CityInline(SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline):
    model = City
    sortable_field_name = "position"

class ProvinceInline(SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline):
    model = Province
    sortable_field_name = "position"
    inlines = (CityInline,)

@admin.register(Country)
class CountryInlineAdmin(SortableHiddenMixin, NestedModelAdmin):
    sortable_field_name = "position"
    inlines = (ProvinceInline,)
```

Are there any ways to sort **the top level items** in **select-to-change list**?

Or, is it impossible to sort **the top level items** with **django-nested-admin**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**django-nested-admin**](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) hasn't supported the sort for **the top level items** in **select-to-change list** yet. Actually, the feature was already requested as you can see [**Add sorting support for changelist view**](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/issues/100).

In addition, the combination of [**django-nested-admin**](https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [**django-admin-sortable2**](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2) doesn't work because they're not integrated each other.